# Horizontal Free Fall

Tags: newtonian-gravity, projectile, free-fall

Let's say you are launched out of a canon at a $0^\circ$ degree angle 5 feet off of the ground. Normally, from my basic understanding of free falling, you have to be move unimpeded with no force acting upon you. If you are shot horizontally, would you be considered free falling if you are consistently moving at terminal velocity of 122mph?

Comment: how is 122 mph considered "terminal velocity"?  are you on an asteroid somewhere?

Comment: How is a terminal velocity compatible with a free fall?  Is there drag?

Comment: I don't know the answer to these questions. I Wikipedia'd some facts before asking. You could be an asteroid somewhere

Comment: @ChrisZog So you are saying the barrel of the canon is horizontal?

Comment: Your horizontal velocity has no effect on how fast you fall. From a height of 5 feet it will take 0.5575 seconds to hit the ground, whether you have any horizontal motion or not.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't you not experience gravity until your forward momentum was slow enough for gravity to affect you?  Otherwise a bullet would drop to the ground almost immediately after being fired from a gun.

Comment: @Rick bullets don’t come out of the barrel horizontal : the barrel is angled upwards. And with adjustable sights there are positions that work for two separate distances due to the elevation, one for when the bullet is rising through the line of sight and one as it falls through the line of sight...

Comment: @SolarMike sorry but a bullet can come out of the gun at any angle you point it.  If I hold it straight horizontal, the bullet will travel a distance before it begins dropping.

Comment: @Rick Consider yourself corrected. As soon as the bullet leaves the barrel it starts accelerating downwards, no matter what the angle of the barrel is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall free fall means unrestricted downward motion in a gravitational field. Any air drag (and terminal velocity) you experience due to your horizontal velocity leaving the canon should have no effect on your downward acceleration $g$.

The only restriction to free fall would be air drag on your downward motion. Since your height out of the canon is only 5 feet, that's hardly enough falling distance for air drag to play any significant role, and you certainly would not reach any downward terminal velocity.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your scenario. If that's the case let me know.

Otherwise, hope this helps.